# Correct syntax for function that returns closure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to port JS code to Rust, and struggling mostly with currying, functions, and closures.

So far, the JS code below:

```js
  const identity = a => a;
  const right = a => b => b;
  const third = a => b => c => c;

  const log = msg => right
    (console.log(msg))
    (msg);
  
  log(identity(true));
  log(right("ignored")([4, 5, 6]));
  log(third("ignored")(3)(99));
```

I can write as follows:

```
fn main() {
  fn identity<T>(a: T) -> T {
    a
  };

  fn right<T, U>(_a: T) -> fn(U) -> U {
    |b| b
  }

  fn third<T, U, V>(_a: T) -> fn(U) -> fn(V) -> V {
    |_b| |c| c
  }

  fn log<T: Debug>(msg: T) -> T {
    right(println!("{:?}", msg))(msg)
  };

  log(identity(true));
  log(right("ignored")((4, 5, 6)));
  log(third("ignored")(3)(99));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c57721b203084321c455f5303901c7e8)

Now:

```js
const undefinedCheck = 
        a => (a == null);// ==
     
const fa = a => f =>
        undefinedCheck(a)
          ? undefined
          : f(a);
          
const f = a => a * 2;
       
console.log(fa(1)(f));
console.log(fa(undefined)(f));
```

I try to implement this code in Rust considering `right` function, however:

```
  fn fa<T, U, V>(a: T) -> fn(U) -> V {
    |f| f(a)
  }
```

This code generates an error:

```
mismatched types

expected fn pointer, found closure

note: expected fn pointer `fn(U) -> V`
            found closure
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rust, `fn` is a concrete function pointer type, while [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) is the `trait` that function/closure/other callable implements. In brief, in Rust, **type** of object is mostly about *what the object is* or *how is the object implemented*, while **traits** an object implements is mostly about *what could the object do* or *what can we do with the object*.

Rust closures does not have same type with functions (the `fn` type), each closure has its [own anonymous type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html). But they may implement same trait like `Fn`/[`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html)/[`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html). We can *call closures*, and we can also *call functions*, but functions are not closures, vice versa.

`impl Trait` grammer ([edition guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html)) should work for your circumstance:

```rust
fn fa<T, U: Fn(T) -> V, V>(a: T) -> impl Fn(U) -> V {
  ...
}
```

However, `impl Trait` requires all `return`s to return the same type, so it won't be possible to return different closures according to some condition. To return "different closures" you need `Box<dyn Trait>` ([edition guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/dyn-trait-for-trait-objects.html?highlight=dyn,tr#dyn-trait-for-trait-objects)) instead.

---

There are still lifetime issues. Here is one solution to the problem, assuming you *can* move `a`:

```rust
fn fa<T, U: Fn(T) -> V, V>(a: T) -> impl FnOnce(U) -> V {
    move |f| {
        f(a)
    }
}
```

Or, you may clone `a`:

```rust
fn fa<T: Clone, U: Fn(T) -> V, V>(a: &T) -> impl FnOnce(U) -> V {
    let a1 = a.clone();
    move |f| {
        f(a1)
    }
}
```

Or you may let `U` to take `&T` instead of `T` (and you need annotate lifetime explicitly then).

You may want to write different versions of functions according to the traits the type parameters implemented. That's not easy according to my limited knowledge, since [*specialization*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210/files) is still unstable, and only applicable to functions in `trait`s.

Comment: Thanks! in fact, I wondered `fn` `Fn` and `trait` issue. Looking forward to your update. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you again! Let me be clear please. Did you suggest `move` or `clone`  `a` are extra abilities and not to suggest mandatory syntax, am I correct?

Comment: `fn fa<T, U: Fn(T) -> V, V>(a: T) -> impl FnOnce(U) -> V {|f| f(a)}` seems to be working, and is this ok for a minimal implementation?

Comment: Moving or Clone a is OK for a minimal example. But for production use (at least, non-toy use) you must take more things into consideration.